# what is necessary for authentication to be secure

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra

I'm currently trying to get a grasp on Sinatra, and i noticed there is no up to date authentication gem like devise for rails. I decided to just create my own authentication system and my question is, what are the most important precautions I need to take to make my users secure? I need to store passwords in hash form, possibly with salt, but what else?
Bear in mind that I'm not security expert, wouldnt be asking this question if it were otherwise.

Comment: This is a bit broad and thus unfit for SO. Read everything on http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authentication ? xd

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". Writing your own authentication system is not something to jump into midstream. I'd recommend working as part of an existing project to improve it and learn what it takes, then consider whether you _really_ want to take it on. SO isn't the place to ask this question though other [se] sites would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encrypt password with **bcrypt gem**

**be cautious with sessions hijacking**

for example

```
post "/signup" do
  password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], password_salt)

  #ideally this would be saved into a database, hash used just for sample
  userTable[params[:username]] = {
    :salt => password_salt,
    :passwordhash => password_hash 
  }

  session[:username] = params[:username]
  redirect "/"
end
```

Comment: could you elaborate on sessions hijacking please?

Comment: Stealing a user's session id lets an attacker use the web application in the victim's name. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-hijacking

Comment: The question is too broad for [so]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing might help you when answering.